# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison cs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Develop a Python method change(amount) that for any integer amount in the range from 24 to 1000 returns a list consisting of numbers 5 and 7 only, such that their sum is equal to amount. For example, change(28) may return [7, 7, 7, 7], while change(49) may return [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7] or [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7] or [7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7].

To solve this quiz, implement the method change(amount) on your machine, test it on several inputs, and then paste your code in the field below and press the submit quiz button. Your submission should contain the change method only (in particular, make sure to remove all print statements).
**MY CODE:**

```
import sys
def change(amount):
    if amount == 24:
        return [5, 5, 7, 7]
    if amount >= int(sys.getrecursionlimit()):
        r = []
        for i in range(0, int(amount / 5)):
            r.append(5)
        return r
    changes = change(amount - 5)
    changes.append(5)
    return changes
```

**I GOT THIS ERROR:**

```
RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 12:
    changes = change(amount - 5))
RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 12:
    changes = change(amount - 5))
RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 12:
    changes = change(amount - 5)
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times])
RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 5:
    if amount == 24:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
)
```

Comment: This code will recurse forever if `amount` becomes negative, or just never becomes equal to 24.

Comment: Your code doesn't take `7` into consideration at all except for the `24` case. You may just need to rethink the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found in the code you provided is that there is no base case, one which will terminate the program if amount becomes less than 0.
Here is my take on your problem (I am assuming that the input will be between 24 and 1000):

```
def change(amount):
    li = []
    
    while amount%5 != 0:
        if amount == 0:
            break
        li.append(7)
        amount -= 7
    
    while amount != 0:
        li.append(5)
        amount -= 5
        
    return li
```

So, to solve your problem, I am using 7 only as a means of getting the amount into a multiple of 5. Here are the possible scenarios:

In the event that the amount is a multiple of 7, the program only considers the first while loop and doesn't enter the second one at all.

In the event that amount is a multiple of 5, it skips the first loop and runs the second one till termination.

In all other cases, it first subtracts 7 until the amount is a multiple of 5, then runs the second loop till termination.